# Prefix hyphen and another prefix hyphen

Tags: hyphenation, suspended-hyphen

In a sentence reading *peri- and post-stimulus* is the first hyphen necessary?

If not, what alternative structure should be used?

Comment: Why do you think it's not necessary? Do you have something against hyphens?

Comment: ***A prefix***  is a half word (e.g., anti-, ex-, post-, pre-) placed before a word to modify its meaning. Most prefixed words can be written with or without a hyphen after the prefix.

***As a guideline,*** avoid the hyphen if you can, but if the unhyphenated version is a spelling mistake (let your spellchecker do its job) or looks too unwieldy for you, use a hyphen.

That said, you should always use a hyphen with ex- and self-, and you should never allow ambiguity to creep in (e.g. you must write re-press the shirt not repress the shirt). http://www.dailywritingtips.com/hyphenating-prefixes/

Comment: @Josh61 But in the case of a lonely prefix, as in the question, the hyphen is generally required.